# Do you have to test for nulls when logging exception cause?

Tags: java, exception

I want to write this stuff to a log when I catch an exception:

```
log(e.getClass().getName());
log(e.getMessage());
log(e.getCause().getClass().getName());
log(e.getCause().getMessage());
```

Do I need to check for null when I call `e.getCause`? Or will it always be populated with a value?

Answer (score 3):

`getCause()` can return null, so you have to check. So - you have to check for `null`. From [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29)

> Returns:
>       the cause of this throwable or null if the cause is nonexistent or unknown.

You can use [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) `ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e.getCause())` or `ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e)`